# Ruby on Rail - Add background task to update status and expiration date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, task, delayed-job, job-scheduling

I am making a auction web app. When a ad is created, I automatically add **expiration date** into database.

```
  before_create :set_expiration_date

  def set_expiration_date
    self.expiration_date =  Time.now + 60.days
  end
```

How can I add a **background task/job**, so when a ad  has reached its **expiration date**, it can change the **`status to false`**.

Is it any good gem that I could use in my case?

I have tried **whenever gem** and it was very cumbersome and it didn't ran in background and hard to understand.

Comment: Generate a `rake` task and then call it periodically.

Comment: Are you using heroku in production?

Comment: @toddmetheny No I am in development (localhost:3000)

Comment: @devanand I have never made rake task, can you help me out.

Comment: You will need a gem to run a rake task periodically, `whenever` is a very good one. https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: @MrYoshiji For me this was mostly a very unstable way. Because some time the server runs more than one instances or all instances were sleeping.

Comment: @Rubioli see anser 1 :)

Comment: clockwork is an option if you're looking for an alternative to whenever: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create background job changing the status in after create callback which would be performed at exp. date

more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough information to be sure, but keep the system updating records sounds a little overcoding for me. Is really necessary to store your model `status` field? I mean, you can also calculate if your records have expired whenever you need it and only when you need it, just add a `scope` to your model like:

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  scope :not_expired, -> { where(:expiration_date > DateTime.now) }
end
```

Then you used it like this:

```
@groceries = Food.not_expired
```

Answer (score 0):

In your lib/tasks file, create a file called `something.rake` and inside that file, create a task by saying:

```
task :name_of_task => :environment do
  # name of model
  Ad.find_each do |ad|
     # if add expired, change status to false and save
  end
end
```

You can run your task by saying `rake name_of_task` in the terminal...or you can add `name_of_task` to the heroku scheduler if you're using heroku. https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler